# MongoDB C# Driver database.GetCollection and magic strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Just getting into the NoSQL stuff so forgive me if this is a simple question. I am trying to somewhat implement a repository type pattern using a generic repository for the more common operations.

One thing that I have run into that is killing this idea is that in order to get the collection you plan to work with you have to pass a string value for the name of the collection.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");
```

This means that I have to hard code my collection names or code up a dictionary somewhere to act as a lookup so that i can map the object type to a collection name.

How is everyone else handling this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is "semi-hardcode." You can put the name of the collection in a class name and refere to it:

```
public class Entity {
  public static readonly string Name = "entities";
}

var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>(Entity.Name);
```

Comment: great idea, I thought about doing that and i can hide that property from MongoDB so that it's not saved in the DB... thanks.

Comment: I've used a similar approach before. I've also seen people use typeof(T).FullName as the collection name.

Comment: That's a good approach, but could potentially be dangerous if the namespaces get changed.

Comment: @JBeckton, you shouldn't have to hide it from Mongo. It's a static field, not an instance field.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a class to manage DB transactions

First you need a base class for all entities:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { set; get; }
}
```

then an static class to manage all:

```
public static class MongoDB
{
    private static string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    public static string DatabaseName { get { return "test"; } }

    private static MongoServer _server;
    private static MongoDatabase _database;

    public static MongoServer Server
    {
        get
        {
            if (_server == null)
            {
                var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
                _server = client.GetServer();
            }

            return _server;
        }
    }

    public static MongoDatabase DB
    {
        get
        {
            if(_database == null)
                _database = Server.GetDatabase(MongoDB.DatabaseName);

            return _database;
        }
    }

    public static MongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : Entity
    {
        return DB.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).FullName);
    }

    public static List<T> GetEntityList<T>() where T : Entity
    {
        var collection = MongoDB.DB.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).FullName);
        return collection.FindAll().ToList<T>();
    }

    public static void InsertEntity<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        GetCollection<T>().Save(entity);
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
 public class SomeEntity : Entity { public string Name {set;get;} }

 MongoDB.InsertEntity<SomeEntity>(new SomeEntity(){ Name = "ashkan" });

 List<SomeEntity> someEntities = MongoDB.GetEntityList<SomeEntity>();
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  I've implemented something similar but mine also plays well with Dependency Injection.  I have a wrapper class for each database (PrimaryMongoDb, StatsMongoDb) and then I register an instance of each with the DI container.  So any class asking for PrimaryMongoDb gets a single instance and then can get any collection like this instanceOfPrimaryDb.GetCollection<SomeType>();  Also, rather than an abstract class you can use an interface; I use IAggregateRoot which simply has an Id.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an approach very usefull for me as all my mongo collections follow a camel case underscore naming convention, so I made a simple string extension to translate the POCO naming convention to my mongo convention.

```
private readonly IMongoDatabase _db;
public IMongoCollection<TCollection> GetCollection<TCollection>() =>
        _db.GetCollection<TCollection>(typeof(TCollection).ToString().MongifyToCollection());
```

This method is inside a class made for handling mongo using dependency injection and it also wraps the default GetCollection to make it a bit more OO

```
public class MongoContext : IMongoContext
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _db;

    public MongoContext()
    {
        var connectionString = MongoUrl.Create(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mongo"].ConnectionString);
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        _db = client.GetDatabase(connectionString.DatabaseName);
        RegisterConventions();
    }

    public IMongoCollection<TCollection> GetCollection<TCollection>() =>
        _db.GetCollection<TCollection>(typeof(TCollection).Name.MongifyToCollection());
...
```

And the extension:

```
// It may require some improvements, but enough simple for my needs at the moment
public static string MongifyToCollection(this string source)
    {
        var result = source.Mongify().Pluralize(); //simple extension to replace upper letters to lower, etc

        return result;
    }
```